# Getting the prompt on Linux

Tags: prompt

Real noob question:
Am trying to search for a file on Linux am using- systemctl to list all the files but after this list has finished displaying my prompt does not return, so am unable to search for the file I require as the prompt does not return i can only see "line 98-130/130 (end). I must end the search before my prompt is returned by using ctl C. I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you typing? `systemctl` is a system management tool, not a mechanism for searching for files

Comment: If you're typing `systemctl` with no other options or arguments, that's equivalent to `systemctl list-units`, and by will use your system's default pager to display the results